# Undo/Redo buttons are vertically stacked in Markdown mode on narrow screens

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stacks-editor

When using Markdown mode in the new Stacks editor on narrow screens, the Undo/Redo buttons are vertically stacked:

[image]

When in rich text mode, the Undo/Redo buttons appear side-by-side, like in the old editor:

[image]

Could the side-by-side layout be used in *both* modes for consistency?

---

([Bug report opened on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/212))

Comment: To make things easier for staff, I suggest also filing a GitHub Issue at https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues

Comment: @Sonic: Thanks, I've now opened a [bug report](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/212) on GitHub.

Comment: Presumably related: [Undo and redo buttons don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381278/335251)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This bug has been fixed upstream](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/212#issuecomment-1215056566) and will be included in the next release (sometime this month).