# Undo and redo buttons don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stacks-editor

The undo and redo buttons don't work. See gif recording below:

[image: screen recording of stacks editor in a mobile device; tapping undo without any effects]

I recorded this on my phone but the buttons don't work in any device. To see the buttons you need to resize your browser window to a mobile viewport size.

Here are the specs of the phone:

- Chrome 104.0.5112.69
- Android 12

Comment: Presumably related: [Undo/Redo buttons are vertically stacked in Markdown mode on narrow screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381213/335251)

Comment: Thanks for the report! I [filed an issue against our GH repository](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/214) so we can better track this issue. We're planning on having a fix for this included in the next editor release (sometime this month).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed upstream](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/993/what-does-upstream-mean) and will be included in the next release. See the [upstream issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/214) for more details.